# SNS HTTPS subscription confirmation not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have created a SNS subscription of a HTTPS endpoint, and after deploying the code I am seeing Pending Confirmation in those subscription, although both instance SNS topics are in the same region, but when I request confirmation from aws console, it gets confirmed immediately. Can someone tell me what can be done?

Comment: Look at the logs of the https endpoint.  Do you see the confirmation messages arriving and being handled correctly?

Comment: I looked at the logs, it arrived only when I manual request confirmation from console, and then it got confirmed